# How do I type this object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

My object looks like this:

```
 const searchOptions: any = {
      fullText: 'hifi',
      'brand.id': [1,2,3,4],
      'category.id': [1,2,3,4],
      'country.id': [1,2,3,4],
      'property.id': [1,2,3,4],
    }
```

and that's very handy because the API accepts the same query params.

How do I type this object in TypeScript?

Comment: please share some more detail of type you want. your array has only 4 digits? or is dynamic? and what about `brand.id`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For typescript 4.1 or later, you can use [Key Remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types)

```js
type Props = 'brand' | 'category' | 'country' | 'property'

type Base = {
  fullText: string
}

type Obj = {
  [Prop in Props as `${Prop}.id`]: number[]
} & Base

const searchOptions: Obj = {
  fullText: 'hifi',
  'brand.id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
  'category.id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
  'country.id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
  'property.id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
}
```

If these props `'brand' | 'category' | 'country' | 'property'` are keys of some object, you can use `keyof SomeObj` to retrieve them

Answer (score 0):

I guess I asked the question wrong, I ended up doing like this:

```
class SearchOptions {
  fullText: string
  'brand.id': string[]
  'category.id': string[]
  'country.id': string[]
  'property.id': string[]
  constructor(
    fullText: string,
    brandId: string[],
    categoryId: string[],
    countryId: string[],
    propertyId: string[],
  ) {
    this.fullText = fullText
    this['brand.id'] = brandId
    this['category.id'] = categoryId
    this['country.id'] = regionCountryCodes
    this['property.id'] = propertyId
  }
}
```